# ClassCastException from LinkedHashSet to String

Tags: java, arrays, exception, linkedhashset

I want to get array of Strings out of LinkedHashSet but I get ClassCastException in line where i try to print my values in foreach loop.

I get that there is something wrong with powerset method but when i tryed to fix it by adding LinkedHashSet inside method i failed.

I belive there is a way to get Strings out of object. Last thought was to write it in file and than parce with regex but it seems to exotic...

Trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashSet cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at Main.main(Main.java:61)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.stream.events.Characters;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

           String set[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
           char rset[] = new char[5];
           String sSet[] = null;
           String s1 = "";
           String s2 = "";
           ArrayList<char[]> arr = new ArrayList();
           arr.add(new char[]{'b','c','d'});
           arr.add(new char[]{'e','a', 'b'});
           arr.add(new char[]{'c','a'});
           arr.add(new char[]{'b','d','c'});
           arr.add(new char[]{'b','d','c'});

           int i=0;
           String buffer = "";
           for (char[] strings : arr) {
               System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
               if(buffer.indexOf(strings[(strings.length)-1]) < 0){
                   buffer = buffer + strings[(strings.length)-1];
               }
               i++;
           }
           rset = buffer.toCharArray();
           Arrays.sort(rset);

           for (String ch : set) {
            s1+=ch + " ";
           }
           for (char ch : rset) {
                s2+=ch + " ";
            }

           System.out.println(s1);
           System.out.println(s2);
           String diff = difference(s1, s2);
           System.out.println(diff);

           //form the power set
           LinkedHashSet myPowerSet = powerset(set);
           //display the power set


           System.out.println(myPowerSet.toString());


           ArrayList<String[]> sArr = new ArrayList(myPowerSet);

           for (String[] strings : sArr) {
               System.out.println(strings);
           }
       }

    private static String difference(String s1, String s2) {
        String diff = "";
        String[] strList1 = s1.split(" ");
           String[] strList2 = s2.split(" ");

           List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(strList1);
           List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(strList2);

           // Prepare a union
           List<String> union = new ArrayList<>(list1);
           union.addAll(list2);

           // Prepare an intersection
           List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<>(list1);
           intersection.retainAll(list2);

           // Subtract the intersection from the union
           union.removeAll(intersection);

           for (String s : union) {
               //System.out.println(s);
               diff += s;
           }
           return diff;
    }

     private static LinkedHashSet powerset(String[] set) {

           //create the empty power set
           LinkedHashSet power = new LinkedHashSet();

           //get the number of elements in the set
           int elements = set.length;

           //the number of members of a power set is 2^n
           int powerElements = (int) Math.pow(2,elements);

           //run a binary counter for the number of power elements
           for (int i = 0; i < powerElements; i++) {

               //convert the binary number to a string containing n digits
               String binary = intToBinary(i, elements);

               //create a new set
               LinkedHashSet innerSet = new LinkedHashSet();

               //convert each digit in the current binary number to the corresponding element
                //in the given set
               for (int j = 0; j < binary.length(); j++) {
                   if (binary.charAt(j) == '1')
                       innerSet.add(set[j]);
               }

               //add the new set to the power set
               power.add(innerSet);

           }
           return power;
       }
       /**
         * Converts the given integer to a String representing a binary number
         * with the specified number of digits
         * For example when using 4 digits the binary 1 is 0001
         * @param binary int
         * @param digits int
         * @return String
         */
       private static String intToBinary(int binary, int digits) {

           String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(binary);
           int foundDigits = temp.length();
           String returner = temp;
           for (int i = foundDigits; i < digits; i++) {
               returner = "0" + returner;
           }
           return returner;
       } 
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the StackTrace?

Comment: Use `LinkedHashSet<String>` instead of `LinkedHashSet` for a start (it might not directly fix your problem, but it will make it safer).

Comment: @AndyTurner Exactly what I was going to post

Comment: Actually, it should be `LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>>` in the case of the return value of `powerset` (but `innerSet` should be `LinkedHashSet<String>`).

Comment: But that's the problem.  He's building a `LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>>` then treating it as if it were a `LinkedHashSet<String[]>`.  Which it isn't.

Comment: Shorten your example to the minimal code needed to reproduce your problem and tell us which line has actually the error. And you mght also want to explain what you try to do in the first place..

Comment: @EugeneShymko you should read the [Generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), especially the bit about "raw types".

Comment: @AndyTurner And than how to assing it to the ArrayList?
Instead of ArrayList<String[]> sArr = new ArrayList(myPowerSet);

Comment: If `myPowerSet` is of type `LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>>`, then `sArr` would need to be of type `ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>`. (Although you don't actually need to copy the set into a list to iterate it, you can just use `myPowerSet` in the enhanced for loop declaration directly).

Comment: And compile your code with `-Xlint:rawtypes`.

Comment: @AndyTurner But i actually need to manipulate values inside, and for that i need tham into array of Strings for exapmle

Comment: @EugeneShymko well I didn't make you put `LinkedHashSet<String>` instances in there  :) Also, what makes you think you can't manipulate the contents of a `LinkedHashSet<String>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner It seems inconvinient for me cose never used it before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help finding flaws in your code, it does help to use Generics all through the code. An IDE like Eclipse will warn you, when you forget to use Generics.

Taking your powerset method and using generics yields the following code:

```
private static Set<Set<String>> powerset(String[] set) {

    // create the empty power set
    Set<Set<String>> power = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    // get the number of elements in the set
    int elements = set.length;

    // the number of members of a power set is 2^n
    int powerElements = (int) Math.pow(2, elements);

    // run a binary counter for the number of power elements
    for (int i = 0; i < powerElements; i++) {

        // convert the binary number to a string containing n digits
        String binary = intToBinary(i, elements);

        // create a new set
        Set<String> innerSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        // convert each digit in the current binary number to the corresponding element
        // in the given set
        for (int j = 0; j < binary.length(); j++) {
            if (binary.charAt(j) == '1')
                innerSet.add(set[j]);
        }

        // add the new set to the power set
        power.add(innerSet);

    }
    return power;
}
```

So the actual object you are returning is a Set of Sets.
As you did not use Generics you can trick yourself (and the compiler) to believe you are using a Set. At runtime it is still a Set> so the ClassCastException is thrown.

The correct method to print your results will be as follows:

```
    for (Set<String> setOfStrings : myPowerSet) {
        System.out.println(setOfStrings);
    }
```

Comment: The `toString()` is redundant in the "method to print your results".

Comment: You are correct and I updated my answer.
It is interesting to note, that the original poster could have left his old printing code and by just using the correct generics it would have been working.

Comment: What if i want to put pure strings them into  ArrayList<String[]> str? I try to use str.add(setOfStrings.toString()); but get compile error The method add(String[]) in the type ArrayList<String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: @EugeneShymko please - take my advice in the comments above - go and read the [generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). It explains problems like this.

Comment: The compiler message is actually quite clear: 
If you have a List<String[]> you can add new String arrays. 

But when you call list.add(xyz.toString()) you are trying to add a single String instead of a String Array.

Comment: @AndyTurner I will, but this project is for my friends in university for test witch on Monday, and also to port it on android, so for now i need to get working code and educational purposes comes next

Comment: Or to put it differently: 
_What if i want to put pure strings them into ArrayList<String[]> str?_

You cannot.
You can have a List<String> and you can add 'pure' Strings
You can have a List<String[]> and you can only add String arrays (String[])

Comment: So you think it'll be faster to blindly fumble onwards until you hit the same problem again? Eh, well, your choice.

Comment: @AndyTurner I get the general idea of different types, and belive i can survive with it till end of the task. Thank you by the way your comments really usefull!

Comment: @EugeneShymko "I get the general idea of different types" I really don't get the impression you do. This entire question is based around a misunderstanding of how to use the Java type system to avoid type errors in your code. I obviously can't force you, but I think you will make back the time you spend reading the tutorial now by not wasting it solving type bugs.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

### Use ***Generics***

---

```
LinkedHashSet myPowerSet;
```

should actually be

```
LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> myPowerSet;
```

Make the necessary changings in your code and the answer will jump right in front of your eyes.

```
ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>> sArr = new ArrayList<>(myPowerSet);
```

Does not actually take `String[]` but `String` since its the type use in `myPowerSet` so the following would also be changed

```
for (Set strings : sArr) {
    System.out.println(strings);
}
```

---

### Full Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String set[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    char rset[] = new char[5];
    String sSet[] = null;
    String s1 = "";
    String s2 = "";
    ArrayList<char[]> arr = new ArrayList<char[]>();
    arr.add(new char[]{'b','c','d'});
    arr.add(new char[]{'e','a', 'b'});
    arr.add(new char[]{'c','a'});
    arr.add(new char[]{'b','d','c'});
    arr.add(new char[]{'b','d','c'});

    int i=0;
    String buffer = "";
    for (char[] strings : arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
        if(buffer.indexOf(strings[(strings.length)-1]) < 0){
            buffer = buffer + strings[(strings.length)-1];
        }
        i++;
    }
    rset = buffer.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(rset);

    for (String ch : set) {
        s1+=ch + " ";
    }
    for (char ch : rset) {
        s2+=ch + " ";
    }

    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);
    String diff = difference(s1, s2);
    System.out.println(diff);

    //form the power set
    LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> myPowerSet = powerset(set);
    //display the power set


    System.out.println(myPowerSet.toString());


    ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>> sArr = new ArrayList<>(myPowerSet);

    for (Set strings : sArr) {
        System.out.println(strings);
    }
}

private static String difference(String s1, String s2) {
    String diff = "";
    String[] strList1 = s1.split(" ");
    String[] strList2 = s2.split(" ");

    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(strList1);
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(strList2);

    // Prepare a union
    List<String> union = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    union.addAll(list2);

    // Prepare an intersection
    List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    intersection.retainAll(list2);

    // Subtract the intersection from the union
    union.removeAll(intersection);

    for (String s : union) {
        //System.out.println(s);
        diff += s;
    }
    return diff;
}

private static LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> powerset(String[] set) {

    //create the empty power set
    LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> power = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    //get the number of elements in the set
    int elements = set.length;

    //the number of members of a power set is 2^n
    int powerElements = (int) Math.pow(2,elements);

    //run a binary counter for the number of power elements
    for (int i = 0; i < powerElements; i++) {

        //convert the binary number to a string containing n digits
        String binary = intToBinary(i, elements);

        //create a new set
        LinkedHashSet<String> innerSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        //convert each digit in the current binary number to the corresponding element
        //in the given set
        for (int j = 0; j < binary.length(); j++) {
            if (binary.charAt(j) == '1')
                innerSet.add(set[j]);
        }

        //add the new set to the power set
        power.add(innerSet);

    }
    return power;
}
/**
 * Converts the given integer to a String representing a binary number
 * with the specified number of digits
 * For example when using 4 digits the binary 1 is 0001
 * @param binary int
 * @param digits int
 * @return String
 */
private static String intToBinary(int binary, int digits) {

    String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(binary);
    int foundDigits = temp.length();
    String returner = temp;
    for (int i = foundDigits; i < digits; i++) {
        returner = "0" + returner;
    }
    return returner;
}
```

---

### Output

```
[b, c, d]
[e, a, b]
[c, a]
[b, d, c]
[b, d, c]
a b c d e 
a b c d 
e
[[], [e], [d], [d, e], [c], [c, e], [c, d], [c, d, e], [b], [b, e], [b, d], [b, d, e], [b, c], [b, c, e], [b, c, d], [b, c, d, e], [a], [a, e], [a, d], [a, d, e], [a, c], [a, c, e], [a, c, d], [a, c, d, e], [a, b], [a, b, e], [a, b, d], [a, b, d, e], [a, b, c], [a, b, c, e], [a, b, c, d], [a, b, c, d, e]]
[]
[e]
[d]
[d, e]
[c]
[c, e]
[c, d]
[c, d, e]
[b]
[b, e]
[b, d]
[b, d, e]
[b, c]
[b, c, e]
[b, c, d]
[b, c, d, e]
[a]
[a, e]
[a, d]
[a, d, e]
[a, c]
[a, c, e]
[a, c, d]
[a, c, d, e]
[a, b]
[a, b, e]
[a, b, d]
[a, b, d, e]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c, e]
[a, b, c, d]
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

Comment: It's not `LinkedHashSet<String> myPowerSet`. Look carefully at what is added to `power` in the `powerset` method.

Comment: You're not understanding what a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) is.

Comment: Im afraid this whay it is not a power set anymore cose output is [e, d, c, b, a] istead of [[], [e], [d], [d, e], [c], [c, e] ...

Comment: @EugeneShymko Just changed it

Comment: @YassinHajaj can I suggest that you don't change the semantics of code if you don't understand what it is meant to do :) All you needed to do to that method was to add the generics.

Comment: @AndyTurner Where exactly did I change the semantics? I only added generics :)

Comment: You changed `power.add(innerSet)` to `power.addAll(innerSet)`, which meant that the return type changed from `Set<Set<String>>` to `Set<String>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Not the case anymore. Changed it when you told me about it. But it's ok to know for the next time.

Comment: Right. I am responding to your comment about "there's a difference between misunderstanding and not knowing" about power sets. If you don't know, don't assume that your changes to code's semantics are correct.

Comment: @AndyTurner To tell you the truth. It is not about understanding, it was about debugging. My bad for not checking what the code was actually producing.